# EasyBCD removed all boot menus

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, easybcd

I recently tried to use EasyBCD to edit some things and apparently ended up corrupting it some how. I'm dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu.

Windows boot manager pops up, now, and says:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. 
To fix the problem:

 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next." 
 3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance. 

File: \Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc0000098
Info: The boot config data file doesn't contain valid information for an operating system.
```

I was wondering if there is any way inside the Ubuntu CD to restore Windows and Ubuntu bootloaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

How I did it:
1. Put in my Ubuntu disk and loaded up [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Used reccomended settings to get Grub back.
2. Created a Windows 8 disk and went into command prompt with it. Used the commands listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/451277/missing-boot-files-in-windows-8).

Comment: What do you mean by "Created a Windows 8 disk"? I'm in a similar situation. I've 2 hard disk. One has Windows 8, the other Linux. Windows upgraded to 8.1 and erased my previous setting (I coudln't boot in Linux anymore). I decided to try easyBSD to setup the boot chain to grub. I added the entry for linux, rebooted: entry for linux didn't worked. I went again on easyBSD, removed the Linux entry, re-created it.... at reboot I didn't have windows anymore in the list (good job easyBSD, good job).

Comment: I've now installed grub on the second disk and set bios to boot from it but there's no way I can boot in Windows anymore now. Even chaining from grub I get the option to start Linux or Linux (windows is gone). I do not have the Windows 8 DVD cause this is a laptop with stupid one key recovery.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to get [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on your linux live cd, and install `grub` using that. Then you can either work with that, or login to windows and redo your EasyBCD setup.

Comment: Okay. That did work for ubuntu, but Windows still brings up the same screen when I go into it using grub.

Comment: @Jack When you were dual booting, Was EasyBCD your main Bootloader or Grub? You would need to rewrite grub over whereever easy bcd was installed, either in the MBR or (now seems more likely) the partition that windows was installed on.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm sorry for the long answer. 
This solution is for the ones with no windows installation or repair disc.

I had a similar problem, the same error message,  but I had no windows installation disc. I couldn't boot Ubuntu either. I thought everything was lost. So then I used Ubuntu live USB which I had and chose to "Try Ubuntu before installing"  and performed boot repair and finally I could get Ubuntu working. (finally relieved that something was working). Then I added windows option to the Ubuntu grub menu. I got windows 8 loader option in the grub while booting but same error when I select it. I googled a lot but found no solution and I  gave up. But finally after a few days I realized something and tried it. It worked right. I hope this would be really helpful for someone out there who struggled like me.

THE  SOLUTION  : EasyBCD actually creates a backup of your BCD file. (or you would have been prompted to create one when you run the software)

I could access windows files from the drive in Ubuntu. Then I searched for the location where easybcd was installed and  and found backups of the bcd file. (gave me little hope that something could be possibly done)

Then I went to the folder "Root" of windows and found a file named BCD. I copied the file to other directory (just in case if I needed  it later).

Next step  I removed the BCD File (I didn't know if it was advisable to do it) and copy pasted the .bcd backup file into  the root folder.(The file had a name like EasyBCD Backup(-date-).bcd    )

Then I renamed the file as BCD ( same as the one I deleted) without the extensions .bcd  (the file I deleted was plainly called BCD)

After that restarted the laptop and chose the windows option from the grub and............ To my surprise..................  it worked.

It was a great relief as I was very new to all these things and had completely lost hope. 
I hope this helps